# On equivalent formulas

Tags: model-theory

Couyld someone give some hints on how to prove this :

Claim: Let  $T$ be a  $\tau$-theory  and $\varphi$ a  $\tau$-formula, that have the same models. Then $\varphi$ is equivalent to a finite conjunction of formulas of $T$.

I was thinking about arguing that if $\mathcal{M} \models T$ then $\mathcal{M} \models \varphi$. So $T \models \varphi$. Then by compactness there must be some finite $\Delta \in T$ such that $\Delta \models \varphi$. Then I claim that $\mathcal{M} \models \varphi $ iff $\mathcal{M} \models \Delta$. Is this correct ?

Comment: You seem to be using the *models* turnstile "$\models$" in two different senses, that $\mathcal{M}$ "models" the theory $T$ and again the formula $\varphi$, but also that $\varphi$ is deducible from theory $T$.  It would be good to use a different turnstile for the latter, and to explicitly define $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks! I intended to use it only as synonym of models! Can you suggest me a better proof strategy ?

Comment: @hardmath - It's not an uncommon practice to write $T\vDash\varphi$ for "$\varphi$ holds in every model in which $T$ holds"; I believe Marker is one author who uses this convention.

Comment: @Malice : Indeed my concern is that a visually distinct form will help articulate the reasoning from satisfaction in (a collection of?) models to deduction (in FOL).

Comment: @hardmath The notation $T\models \varphi$ is standard in model theory to mean "every model of $T$ satisfies $\varphi$". It's important to distinguish this notion from $T\vdash \varphi$, which means "there is a proof of $\varphi$ from $T$" (even though $T\models \varphi$ and $T\vdash \varphi$ are equivalent by the completeness theorem). I understand your concern that overloading notation can be confusing, but I wouldn't suggest that the OP use nonstandard notation, especially since the OP doesn't seem to be confused at all!

Comment: I suspect this question has been posed in a purely model-theoretic setting, where deduction in FOL is irrelevant. It is also standard in model theory to use "equivalent" to mean "has the same class of models".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your argument is correct. As long as your definition of "$\varphi$ is equivalent to $\Delta$" is that $\varphi$ and $\Delta$ have the same models.

The last step could do with some more explanation. The reasoning is hidden below.

> If $\mathcal{M}\models \varphi$, then $\mathcal{M}\models T$ (by assumption), so $\mathcal{M}\models \Delta$ (since $\Delta\subseteq T$). And conversely, if $\mathcal{M}\models \Delta$, then $\mathcal{M}\models \varphi$, since $\Delta\models \varphi$.

Comment: I suspect the problem might have been posed with the definition of "$\varphi$ is equivalent to $\Delta$" being "$\vdash \varphi \iff \Delta$".  After all, it is given: "Let $T$ be a τ-theory and $\varphi$ a τ-formula, that have the same models."

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicit the compactness argument.

Since any model of $\varphi$ is a model of $T$, one has $\varphi \vdash T$. In particular, for any conjunction of conjunctions of formulas of $T$, say $\Delta$, we have $\vdash \varphi \to \Delta$.

Assume for a contradiction that $\varphi$ isn't equivalent to any finite conjunction of elements of $T$. Then, the following set is finitely consistent :
$$T' := \{\Delta \wedge \neg \varphi \ \big| \ \Delta \textrm{ finite conjunction of formulas in } T \} $$

But a model of $T'$ is a model of $T$ that satisfies $\neg \varphi$, a contradiction.